# $watch or ng-change, to detect onchange on a range input and process according to the value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to AngularJS/Ionic and I am trying to detect the change of value of an input type="range", and to do things in js depending on this value.

But I am not sure how to detect it : $watch or ng-change ?

Here's the code :
HTML:

```
    <html ng-app="SnowBoard">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Checkboxes</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ComputeCtrl">

    <ion-content>

      <div class="range">
        <input id="levelrange" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" name="userlevelofsurfing" ng-model="levelvalue" ng-change="setLevelText()">
        {{levelvalue}}
      </div>

      <div id="leveldisplay">
      </div> 

      {{testvariable}}

    </ion-content>

  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
   angular.module('SnowBoard', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })


    .state('app.browse', {
      url: "/browse",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/compute.html",
          controller: 'ComputeCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/playlists');
})

.controller('ComputeCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout) {

  $scope.data = {
    levelvalue: 5,
    level1wordDescription: "INTERMEDIATE+",
    testvariable: "dummy"
  }

  $scope.$watch('data.levelvalue', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log('data.levelvalue is now '+newVal);  
    console.log('data.levelvalue is now '+data.levelvalue);

  });

  $scope.setLevelText = function(rangeValue) {
    console.log('range value has changed to :'+$scope.data.levelvalue);
    $scope.data.testvariable = $scope.data.levelvalue;
  }



});
```

http://codepen.io/LouisDoe/pen/jEEJxd

Answer (score 3):

You could use either, though I recommend ngChange in this case. When you are watching an input, ngChange is usually the best choice. You should minimize $scope.$watch expressions for performance, and in this case it would duplicate what ngChange already handles. Remove the $watch.

Your problem here is in the ng-model. You did not reference it correctly, you have `levelvalue` when your model is actually `data.levelvalue`. Also I removed the `value="5"` attribute, as ngModel takes care of this and it was getting in the way.

```
<input id="levelrange" type="range" min="0" max="10" name="userlevelofsurfing" ng-model="data.levelvalue" ng-change="setLevelText()">
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, if I use `ng-change="setLevelText()` instead of `ng-change="setLevelText(data.levelvalue)` the function doesn't work...

Comment: See this, you don't need to pass the value because it is already on the $scope and you don't even use it in your change event method. http://codepen.io/gnomeontherun/pen/ZYGWzJ